Верна ли тут пунктуация?
В этот день с точки зрения справедливости и людской, и божественной я считаю, свершился акт правосудия.

Правильно:
В этот день, с точки зрения справедливости и людской, и божественной,  я считаю, свершился акт правосудия.
Пояснение

Дискуссионным является вопрос об обособлении обстоятельства "с точки зрения справедливости и людской, и божественной". В данном случае это актуализация распространенного речевого оборота. Сравнить: В этот день свершился акт правосудия.

Обособляется вводное предложение "я считаю" по правилу Розенталя, которое по смыслу примыкает к обособленному обстоятельственному обороту:
1. Запятыми выделяются вводные предложения следующих 
типов: 1) личные нераспространенные предложения типа я 
думаю, я знаю, я вижу, я помню и др.: Я чаю, небо с 
овчинку показалось (П.); Вот у меня, я думаю, получше 
глаза (Г.); 



